# Closed vs was closed

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

> 1. There used to be a hotel near the airport, but **it closed** a long time ago
> 2. There used to be a hotel near the airport, but **it was closed** a long time ago

In *English Grammar in Use*, the first one is used. Why?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [“The shop opened by” vs “The shop was opened by”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116215/), but as yet that one has no upvoted answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatical. The first is much more idiomatic.

I haven't got a definite answer for why it is preferred; but I think it is because
it doesn't invite the question "Who closed it", where the second does. You would use the second if you wanted to emphasise that somebody closed it.

Comment: You could look at this from the *active/passive* perspective, but alternatively it could be seen as a matter of whether ***to close*** is being used transitively or intransitively. Either way though, I think one could apply the basic principle *use the simplest tense form available* unless there's a clear-cut reason to do otherwise (as you say - in this particular case, ***if** you wanted to emphasise that somebody closed it*).

Comment: It may be worth noting that "to close" is an [ergative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb).  Ergative verbs can express much the same sentiment in both active and passive constructions: "the store closed" and "the store was closed" are similar.  Other verbs express distinct relationships: "the cow ate" and "the cow was eaten" are quite different.